# Implement a 4g toggle for android (private only)

Tags: java, android, reflection, rooted-device, lte

Im building an application which needs to toggle the networkmode e.g. from 4g to 3g, to simulate a inter-MSC handover. Since this application will be private only, and the device is rooted, I am open fo any ideas to achieve that.

First thing I tried was Reflection. I tried to get Access to the BaseCommands-Class which implements
the CommandsInterface-Interface. But i was not successfull with that.

Since the device is rooted and since the app will never be published, Im fine with any strategy/Idea
 even things like direct manipulation of Systems.Properties or other things like that.

Hope someone of you has some good ideas :>

Comment: I too am trying to accomplish this and have been for months.  If you have figured this out please post, if anyone else knows how to do this, please answer.  Thanks.